# Read an excel column and put its unique values in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, macros, vba

I have a column with different values. I have to select only unique values from the column and put in an array.

I am using following code for the same but it puts unique values in another column rather array.

```
Sub GetUniqueSections()
Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim a(8) As String
Dim j
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1

Next i

Range("R2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.Keys)
End Sub
```

Comment: So you know that you will have 8 unique values?

Comment: What do you want to do with the array after it is populated?

Answer (score 3):

In the code below, `UniqueValueArrayFromRange` replaces your `GetUniqueSections` using the same technique with a `Scripting.Dictionary`. You can substitute `"A1:A14"` with whatever you need and the output array will be in `arr`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' pass range values to function for unique values
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A14")
    arr = UniqueValueArrayFromRange(rng)

    ' test return values
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next i

End Sub

Function UniqueValueArrayFromRange(ByRef rngSource As Range) As Variant
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim rngCell As Range

    ' create dictionary and only add new values
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rngCell In rngSource
        If Not dic.Exists(rngCell.Value) Then
            dic.Add rngCell.Value, 1
        End If
    Next rngCell

    ' return key collection as array
    UniqueValueArrayFromRange = dic.Keys

End Function
```

Comment: Very Nice! You could remove `rng.Select` in `Sub Test()`, though. It's not necessary.